Handling categorical values in scikit-learn pipeline and consistent encoding across datasets with MLflow
I have created a function that implement scikit-learn's pipeline into machine learning model but when I print out the target column (before splitting the dataset), it's still category value.
Besides, how can I log the model into the mlflow so in future the model is able to encode the features/ target consistently. For example, there is Dataset A and there are 3 categories: A, B and C and the model encode A,B,C as 1,2,3 but in future let's say there is a new dataset/ or in predict phase the dataset only has B and C and the model must able to encode it as 2 and 3 instead of 1 and 2. For now, when I log the model into the mlflow, it doesn't show any inputs in the artifact.
P/S: Im using Iris dataset
Following is my function codes:
def create_pipeline(self, train_feature, train_label, encoding_method, model):
    feature_cols = train_feature.columns

    if encoding_method == EncodingMethod.ONE_HOT: 
        categorical_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[('onehot', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore',
                                                                        sparse=False))])
        
        preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('category', categorical_transformer, feature_cols)],remainder='passthrough')

        label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
        train_label = pd.Series(label_encoder.fit_transform(train_label))

    elif encoding_method == EncodingMethod.LABEL:
        categorical_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[('label', LabelEncoder())])

        preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('category', categorical_transformer, feature_cols)],
                                            remainder='passthrough')
        
        label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
        train_label = pd.Series(label_encoder.fit_transform(train_label))
        
    pipeline = Pipeline(steps=[('preprocessor', preprocessor),
                                ('classifier', model)])
    
    return pipeline

This is my script:
df = self._dataset.as_dataframe()

train_feature = df[self._train_configs.feature_cols]
train_label = df[self._train_configs.target_col]

self._model = self.create_pipeline(train_feature, train_label, self._train_configs.encoding_method, self._model)
print("\n")
print("This is model")
print(self._model)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(train_feature, train_label, random_state=0, train_size=0.8)
print("\n")
print("This is y_train")
print(y_train.head())

experiment = mlflow.get_experiment_by_name(self.project_id)
with mlflow.start_run(experiment_id=experiment.experiment_id):
    self._model.fit(X=X_train, y=y_train)
    self._model.score(X_test, y_test)

    mlflow.sklearn.log_model(self._model, "pipeline/model")

Output of my self._model
Pipeline(steps=[('preprocessor',
                 ColumnTransformer(remainder='passthrough',  
                                   transformers=[('category',
                                                  Pipeline(steps=[('onehot',
                                                                   OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore',
                                                                                 sparse=False))]),
                                                  Index(['SepalLengthCm', 'SepalWidthCm', 'PetalLengthCm', 'PetalWidthCm'], dtype='object'))])),
                ('classifier',
                 RandomForestClassifier(max_depth=3,
                                        max_features=<RandomForestFeatureSelectionStrategy.SQUARE_ROOT: 'sqrt'>,
                                        max_samples=0.1, n_estimators=20))])

Output of my y_train
This is y_train
137     Iris-virginica
84     Iris-versicolor
27         Iris-setosa
127     Iris-virginica
132     Iris-virginica

